# How to draw ROC curve for a multi-class dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc, multi-class

I have a multi-class confusion matrix as below and would like to draw its associated ROC curve for one of its classes (e.g. class 1).
I know the "one-VS-all others" theory should be used in this case, but I want to know how exactly we need to change the threshold to obtain different pairs of TP and corresponding FP rates.[image]

Comment: There is something very strange about that table.  Are the class numbers ordered in some sense? If something is predicted as class 9 then it is in class 8, if it is predicted to be class 5 then it is probably in class 4, and may similar examples

Comment: @Henry  Yes they are in order. The examples by you are actually included in false positives for class 8 and 4, respectively.

Comment: Those would be false negatives for class 8 (they are actually class 8, but are predicted as not-class-8). I agree with Henry that the table looks unusual in that the true class is almost always numerically lower than the predicted class. I think his question was not are the labels ordered properly, but are the classes *ordinal*? As in, do these represent something like hair color or country which has no inherent ordering, or something like income or age bracket, which does have an inherent ordering? A table like this would make more sense with ordinal data than categorical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use something like softmax to get probability estimates for each class. So, let's say we want to calculate the ROC curve for class $c$. For each sample, you'll get $P(y=c|x)$ from the softmax, and one minus this is the probability of "others", i.e. in this case it can be referred as negative, which means the class $c$ samples are positive. Then, by changing the threshold in the range $[0,1]$, you'll obtain the number of TP and FP for each threshold, which you can directly plot.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by "changing the threshold in the range [0, 1]"

Comment: ROC is plotted by changing a threshold and classifying the sample according to $P(y=c|x)$ value wrt to threshold. So, if $P(y=c|x)=0.8$, and your threshold is $0.9$, the sample is classified as negative. That way, you can obtain TP, FP for each threshold value and plot a ROC.

Comment: Could you please provide me a concrete example based on my given confusion matrix? @gunes

Comment: You cannot calculate a Roc curve from confusion matrix. You need the probability values, and then classify bases on the threshold.

Comment: Okay, and is there is piece of code or specific built-in function doing so? @gunes

Comment: If your model outputs the probabilities for each class, you can code the rest. For example, if you're using a neural network with a softmax layer, you can get the probabilities from the last layer.